# Suppose $a,b,c > 0$. Then there are finitely many integer $x,y$ with $a^x > cb^y$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here is the question:  [image: here]

For this question, it says to find finitely many positive numbers pairs of x and y for to fulfill the inequality.

My thought is when [A] bigger than 1 or b is smaller than 1, then all values of x and y will satisfy the inequality. However, the answer is (d). But for d, if x increases and y cannot decrease to negative, as they are positive whole number, the inequality cannot hold. Why is the answer (d)

Comment: The problem asks for cases where there are a *finite* number of solutions, not infinite.

Comment: Hint: if $a>1$ then $a^{x+1}>a^x$

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a solution $(x,y)$. So $a^x>c\,b^y$. Then:

- $a>1 \implies a^{x+1}>a^x>c\,b^y$ so $(x+1,y)$ is also a solution. By induction, there are then infinitely many solutions of the form $(X,y)$ where $X>x$ is a whole number.
- $b<1 \implies c\,b{y+1}<c\,b^y<a^x$ so $(x,y+1)$ is also a solution. By induction, there are then infinitely many solutions of the form $(x,Y)$ where $Y>y$ is a whole number.

But if $a>1$, then there is a solution of the form $(x,1)$ for $x$ sufficiently large such that $a^x>bc$.
If $b<1$, then there is a solution of the form $(1,y)$ for $y$ sufficiently large such that $b^y<\frac{a}{c}$.
So if either $a>1$ or $b<1$, there are an infinite number of solutions.
Hence, for a finite number of solutions we require the opposite:

$$a<1\text{ and }b>1$$